# Eclipse Background Job: Process specific calls in the Main thread?

Tags: eclipse, multithreading, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

I've been working on an Eclipse-Plugin for a while (my first one, everything is very new).

Now I've realized that I have to add threading by using background jobs, because I don't want the GUI to be frozen during the long processes in my Plugin. But because I didn't think (or know) about this when I started coding, I have multiple GUI-accesses sprinkled all over the long-running processes, therefore I can't simply put them into a job.

Is there any way I can, from inside a job, make those GUI-acccesses to be processed in the Main thread? Otherwise I will have to change the structure of my whole Plugin which is kinda a lot of work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `Display` `asyncExec` or `syncExec` methods to run a `Runnable` in the UI thread from your job.

```java
Display.getDefault().asyncExec(runnable);
```

`asyncExec` just schedules the runnable to run as soon as possible. `syncExec` blocks until the runnable has executed.

If you are using Java 8 you can use a lambda for the runnable:

```java
Display.getDefault().asyncExec(() -> { code });
```

If you want to do something like prompt for a value use a `Runnable` class that saves the result and use `syncExec` to run it:

```java
class PromptRunnable implements Runnable
{
  private String result;

  public void run()
  { 
    result = .... some prompt dialog
  }

  String getResult()
  {
    return result;
  }
}

PromptRunnable doPrompt = new PromptRunnable();

Display.getDefault().syncExec(doPrompt);

String result = doPrompt.getResult();
```

Comment: I have added an example of doing that